# Cannot POST ajax request

Tags: ajax, reactjs

can anyone explain to me why i cannot post the ajax request. When i run this code the console appear POST http://localhost:8080/api/users 404 (Not Found), and in the networth part the preview is 404 not found 
In the index.js file

```
        var path = require('path');
    var express = require('express');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var config = require('./webpack.config.dev.js');

    var app = express();
    var compiler = webpack(config);
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var users = require('./server/routes/users');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use('/api/users', users);

    app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: config.output.publicPath
    }));

    app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(8080, 'localhost', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Listening at http://localhost:8080');
    });
```

and the users file

```
    var express = require('express')
    var router = express.Router()

    // middleware that is specific to this router
    function validateInput(data) {
      let errors = {};

      if (Validator.isNull(data.username)){
        errors.username = "This field is required";
      }
      if (Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
        errors.email = "Email is invalid";
      }
      if (Validator.isNull(data.password)){
        errors.password = 'This field is required';
      }
      if (Validator.isNull(data.passwordConfirmation)){
        errors.passwordConfirmation = 'This field is required';
      }
      if (Validator.equals(data.password, data.passwordConfirmation)){
        errors.passwordConfirmation = 'Password must match';
      }
      return {
        errors,
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
      }
    }

    router.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {

          console.log('runiing the router/post');
          console.log(req.body);
          const {errors, isValid} = validateInput(req.body);

          if (!isValid) {
            res.status(400).json(errors);
          }

    });

    module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `users.js` file the function should be

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

          console.log('runiing the router/post');
          console.log(req.body);
          const {errors, isValid} = validateInput(req.body);

          if (!isValid) {
            res.status(400).json(errors);
          }

    });
```

Because `index.js` have already resolved `/api/users` part in the request url `http://localhost:8080/api/users` at this point. So you only have to map after the `/api/users` in your `users` js file.

For example, if you have following function in `users.js` file

```
router.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
      ...
    }
```

It will resole to the path `http://localhost:8080/api/users/1`

**Edit**
In your existing version,

```
router.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  ...
}
```

will resolve as `http://localhost:8080/api/users/api/users`

Comment: what is the difference between post('/') and the old ver? tks u very much

Comment: I edited the answer, please check whether you got all clear or not.

Comment: @HaNguyen did you get the answer for your question?

Comment: Please accept it as correct answer if it solves your problem. If you have more questions,please comment here. I'm more than happy to help you.

Comment: @HaNguyen Please accept it as correct answer if it solves your problem. If you have more questions,please comment here. I'm more than happy to help you.